# Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp returning Unauthorized Error 401

Tags: google-apps-script, export, google-docs, urlfetch

This is the code I'm using.

```
function doc_to_html(id)
{
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+id+"&exportFormat=html";
var param = 
    {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions:true,
    };
 var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  Logger.log(html);
}
```

It worked several times for testing, but now it's returning "Unauthorized
Error 401." More accurately, it is returning:

```
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I've looked into all the documentation I could find about UrlFetchApp and didn't see any quota or restrictions. I checked the script scope and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request is authorized.

Comment: Well, is that document accessible to the user that this script executes as?

Comment: Yes. I created the script in a Google Sheets file and have full Edit permissions to the Doc file it is accessing. It did work several times before failing suddenly.

Comment: For example, when you use your script to your other Google Document, how was the error?

Comment: The error above is the only error returned. I ran it thrice and it returned properly.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas can't see how 3 runs should blow out the quota

Comment: @Norfeldt exactly, thus my confusion

Comment: Where you able to run the script again successfully (three times) after 24 hours?

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer remember what this was attached to last August

Answer (score 5):

The scopes provided are insufficient to access the document. To access it, you'd need  documents scope as well. Edit the manifest file to have these scopes:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"],
```

Or add a dummy call to Document App in your script:

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
```

---

Based on comments from [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653), It  seems that Documents scope wasn't enough, but Spreadsheet scope is also needed, even though we don't access spreadsheets. Alternatively, Drive's readonly scope is required.

#### Spreadsheet+Document scope:

Manifest:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
```

Or add a dummy call to Document App+SpreadsheetApp in your script:

```
//DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
//SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

#### Drive scope:

Manifest:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],
```

Or add a dummy call to DriveApp in your script:

```
//DriveApp.getFiles()
```