# Converting Google Sheet to Excel then sending as an email attachment works, but cannot access XLXS file (Unauthorized Error 401)

Tags: excel, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below works to convert and send a google sheets as an excel file over email, but the file does not have the actual excel, just Unauthorized Error 401.

```
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){

try { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

var params = {
  method      : "get",
  headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};

var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");

MailApp.sendEmail("Horgstar1212@gmail.com", "Google Sheet to Excel", "The XLSX file is  attached", {attachments: [blob]});}

catch (f) {
  Logger.log(f.toString()); }
}
```

I believe it has something to do with authorization to access the file, but I am very new to coding and API's, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

Your code works fine for me.

According to the error message you are getting, you must be having some authorization issues and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990923/google-apps-script-urlfetchapp-returning-unauthorized-error-401) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812174/unauthorized-401-error-while-execute-as-me) make sure to include in the Manifest file the following Spreadsheet & Document scopes:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
```

and the `appsscript.json` should look like that:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
}
```

Although I post the recommended approach of generating and sending an excel file.

### Recommended Approach:

```
function myFunction() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const nameFile = ss.getName() + ".xlsx";
const requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ss.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx";
const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
const contents = result.getContent();
    
MailApp.sendEmail("Horgstar1212@gmail.com", 
                  "Google Sheet to Excel",
                   "The XLSX file is  attached", 
                  {attachments:[{fileName:nameFile, content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});     
}
```